# Inline form validation returns empty formset.errors list

Tags: django, django-templates, inline-formset

I have the following inline formset:

```
CreateClientFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Client,
    EventType,
    fields=(
        'name',
    ),
    extra=0,
    can_delete=True,
    min_num=1,
    validate_min=True,
    widgets={
        'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class':'form-control',
            'maxlength' : 50
        })
    })
```

And the following view:

```
def create_client(request):
    form = CreateClient()
    formset = CreateClientFormset(instance=Client())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateClient(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            client_saved = form.save(commit=False)
            client_formset = CreateClientFormset(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=client_saved)

            if client_formset.is_valid():
                client_saved.save()
                client_formset.save()

                return redirect(clients)
            else:
                print client_formset.errors
    else:
        print form.errors

    return render(request, 'create_client.html', {'form' : form, 'formset' : formset})
```

When I try to submit an empty value to the formset, it prints the error to the console but it doesn't do anything in the template.

This is my template:

```
{% for field in formset %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
    <tr>
        <td><label>{{ field.name.label }}</label></td>
            <td>
              {% if field.instance.pk %}{{ field.DELETE }}{% endif %}
              {{ field.name }}
              {{ formset.errors }}
              {{ field.id }}
              {% for hidden in formset.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
              {% endfor %}
            </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`{{ formset.errors }}` displays `[]`, even before the form submission.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where is the part of the view where you display the template?

Comment: See the edit @DanielRoseman, at the bottom of the "view" part.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it like this:

```
if client_formset.is_valid():
    client_saved.save()
    client_formset.save()

    return redirect(clients)
else:
    print client_formset.errors
    return render(request, 'create_client.html', {'form' : form, 'formset' : formset, 'formset_errors' : client_formset.errors})
```

And in the template:

```
{% for field in formset %}
    <tr>
        <td><label>{{ field.name.label }}</label></td>
        <td>
            {% if field.instance.pk %}{{ field.DELETE }}{% endif %}
            {{ field.name }}
            {% if formset_errors %}
                {% for errors in formset_errors %}
                    {% for error in errors.values %}
                        {{ error }}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ field.id }}
            {% for hidden in formset.hidden_fields %}
                {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You render `formset`:

```
return render(request, 'create_client.html', {'form' : form, 'formset' : formset})
```

but the one loaded with your form data/errors is `client_formset`:

```
print client_formset.errors
```

The second one you need to pass to render since you are using `{{ formset.errors }}` in your template.